# how to invoke ViewWillDisappear for DetailsViewController in iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have written a piece of code to create a record in Core DB in ViewWillDisappear. but unable to test that on simulator as ViewWillDisappear is never invoked. What kind of operation should i do to invoke it. tried stopping from Xcode no luck.

may be a silly one. but needs pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: What view setup do you use? viewWillDisappear is called whenever there is a view controller transition (navigating in a UINavigationController or doing modal transitions)

Answer (score 0):

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear%3a)
says :

> This method is called in response to a view being removed from a view hierarchy. This method is called before the view is actually removed and before any animations are configured.
>   Subclasses can override this method and use it to commit editing changes, resign the first responder status of the view, or perform other relevant tasks. For example, you might use this method to revert changes to the orientation or style of the status bar that were made in the viewDidDisappear: method when the view was first presented. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

You have to pop this view controller from the navigation stack or to push another view controller from it in order to invoke viewWillDissapear

Comment: its the only VC and no more to push or pop. So as per the doc ViewWil disappear will not be called. Then i am worried what if the user fills the text field and leaves the screen. I want hot persist the data? any ideas?

Comment: In order to leave the screen the user has to hit the Home button,so method - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application in the appDelegate is called